# Keypoint matching using HoG and SIFT

Tags: python, computer-vision, opencv

I have two images and I've found their keypoints using sift keypoint detector,
Now I have to match their keypoints with HoG features,
I know how to extract HoG description, 
but I dont know how to combine it with SIFT and match the keypoints,
any ideas pls?
I am using opencv and python3

Comment: Would you mind sharing some of your code?

Comment: @wacax I have no idea how to code this

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can use brute force or a smart [feature matcher implemented in openCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/dc3/tutorial_py_matcher.html). 
Another approach is seeing the task as [image registration based on extracted features](https://www.learnopencv.com/image-alignment-feature-based-using-opencv-c-python/).

The question may be what is the relation of HoG and SIFT if one image has only HoG and other SIFT or both images have detected both features HoG and SIFT.

Comment: can I detect keypoints using HoG only? I searched a lot and I found out HoG is a descriptor, so I need a detector first. 
I want to use a sift detector and a HoG descriptor for both images

Comment: I would recommend using rather SIFT, SURF or ORB, those are standard options :)